# How to make sure that parser.cmi is generated before lexer

Tags: compiler-construction, makefile, ocaml

I have found a [source](http://cristal.inria.fr/~remy/poly/compil/ppc.tar.gz) of a small compiler of Pseudo Pascal written in OCaml. Everything looks good, but when I launch `make`, it got an error:

```
ocamlc.opt -g -w p -c lexer.ml
File "lexer.mll", line 2, characters 0-11:
Error: Unbound module Parser
make: *** [lexer.cmo] Error 2
```

It seems that it tries to develop lexer before running parser. The Makefile is [here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/628183/), I am not very good at Makefile, could anyone help me find where I could modify a little bit to make sure this execution order?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, I don't think you need to modify anything.  There is a bunch of dependency generation stuff in the Makefile, but you need to run it manually with:

```
make depend
```

before:

```
make
```